# woocommerce_update_product does not get vendor terms on save

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using woocommerce_update_product hook to get product data once a product has been created / updated.

I'm trying to get the terms from a taxonomy called wcpv_product_vendors. On first save (as draft) I can get the other product_cat terms but the terms for wcpv_product_vendors don't appear until I next save the post.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', [$this, 'dcgsql_update_product'], 50, 1);

public function dcgsql_update_product(){

  $get_vendors = get_the_terms($product_id, 'wcpv_product_vendors');
    if (!empty($get_vendors)) {
        foreach ($get_vendors as $vendor) {
            $vendorsarray[] = $vendor->term_id;
        }
        $vendors = implode(',',$vendorsarray);
    } else {
        $vendors = '';
    }    

}
```

On first save as draft, $get_vendors is always empty but I have  applied one.

All other terms for product_cat are coming back fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below codes it will work...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_update_product', 'dcgsql_update_product', 50, 1);

public function dcgsql_update_product(){

  $get_vendors = wp_get_post_terms($product_id, 'wcpv_product_vendors');
    if (!empty($get_vendors)) {
        foreach ($get_vendors as $vendor) {
            $vendorsarray[] = $vendor->term_id;
        }
        $vendors = implode(',',$vendorsarray);
    } else {
        $vendors = '';
    }    

}
```

Comment: Thanks but it hasn't resolved the issue. Its still not fetching the data.

Comment: will you check $get_vendors is able to fetch data or not?